# list should be a lambda expression

Tags: lambda, lisp

I've just started learning LISP and I'm just getting my head around the logic for it, however I've run into an error I can't find the solution for..I'm sure it's because I've misused a parentheses somewhere or I've misused a function in general, but I've been staring at it for an hour now and haven't made any progress!

```
(defun not-touching (pos player move)
   (let (legal? t)
    if ((not (eq (member move '(0 1 2 3 4 7 8 11 12 13 14 15)) nil))
        (mapcar #'(lambda(x) (if (not (member move x) nil)
                                (cond ((and (eq (nth (- (position move x) 1) x) nil)
                                        (not (eq (nth (+ (position move x) 1) x) player))) t)   
                                    ((and (not (eq (nth (- (position move x) 1) x) player))
                                        (not (eq (nth (+ (position move x) 1) x) player))) t)
                                    ((and (not (eq (nth (- (position move x) 1) x) player))
                                        (eq (nth (+ (position move x) 1) x) nil)) t)
                                    (t setf legal? nil))
                                nil)) *outside-lines*))
    legal?))
```

and the error that I'm getting looks like this:

```
SYSTEM::%EXPAND-FORM: (NOT (EQ (MEMBER MOVE '(0 1 2 3 4 7 8 11 12 13 14 15)) NIL)) should be
  a lambda expression
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Too many parentheses. Remove one before `not`, otherwise it looks like a function application. And you're missing parentheses in `let`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to program, you need to learn the syntax of the programming language.

Consult the [Common Lisp Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/Contents.htm) for Common Lisp syntax. Each function/macro/special operator/... of Common Lisp is described in the Common Lisp Hyperspec with its syntax.

See the syntax for LET, IF.

`LET` expects a list of bindings.

`IF`, `SETF` is a form. Needs parentheses around it.

`NOT` takes only one argument.

Comment: Thanks :) And I know, it's been a bit of a learning curve, my lecturer does next to nothing on syntax, he only gives a basic example of how it's used, the rest is up to you!

Comment: @user1693910: fortunately there are a lot of resources for learning. The Hyperspec describes the language, there are free books, good compilers (like Clozure CL and SBCL), ...